# How to create a vector of message_filters::Subscriber?

Tags: c++, ros2

When I try to create a vector of message_filters::Subscriber like so:

```
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>> pc_subscribers_;
    message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2> sub;
    pc_subscribers_.push_back(sub);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
...
/home/sam/work/radar_ws/src/radar_velocity_cpp/src/publisher_radar_ego_comp.cpp:56:31:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:146:4: error: use of deleted function ‘message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::Subscriber(const message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
  146 |  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/sam/work/radar_ws/src/radar_velocity_cpp/src/publisher_radar_ego_comp.cpp:3:
/opt/ros/foxy/include/message_filters/subscriber.h:102:7: note: ‘message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::Subscriber(const message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  102 | class Subscriber : public SubscriberBase, public SimpleFilter<M>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you're invoking this you would be creating a copy of the `Subscription` object. You don't want to do this as `Subscriptions` are stateful. Two copies of the subscription would mean that you'd get two invocations of each incoming message. Instead you should use a SharedPtr and store it in your vector instead of copying the subscription object into your vector.

The `message_filter::Subscription` contains a `rclcpp::Subscription` internally, so I'm talking more about the internal capability but the higher level one displays the same traits because of the internal storage.

In general we recommend storing and using `SharedPtr`s instead of the raw datatype to avoid this sort of issue. [For example how to subscribe](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html#write-the-subscriber-node)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here are the lines changed based on [@Tully](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/161/tully)'s answer

```
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>>> pc_subscribers_;
    pc_subscribers_.push_back(std::make_shared<message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>>(this, sensor_topic));
    return 0;
}
```